# Get NSE Data (Nifty-50) with custom timeframes using python API's

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I tried searching to extract NSE Data for stocks and indices data for custom timeframes such as intervals-

`intervals: [1m, 2m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 60m, 90m, 1h,2h,3h, 1d, 5d, 1wk, 1mo, 3mo]`

Found some Python libraries such as investpy,nsepy,nsetools,yahoo finance but its giving historical data on daily basis.

Yahoo finance support some intervals but it extract only last 60 days of data,while I am checking for more than last 1 year of data.

I am checking for free API providers, I know some paid Data Vendors which provides data for all intervals such as kite connect.

https://github.com/zerodha/pykiteconnect